# Send Soap Request with .PFX file via php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I try to do SOAP request with .pfx file and i got error like:

`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
 : failed to load external entity`

my code look like that :

```
    $this->api_url = "https://wsa.clalbit.co.il/CalcCampaignPremia.asmx?WSDL";

    $certificate   = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/ws-hova.pfx';
    $options       = array(
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'trace'          => 1,
        'local_cert'     => $certificate,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create( array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        ) )
    );

    try {
        $this->soap = new SoapClient( $this->api_url, $options );
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

can't understand why it is not working.

thank's for any advice

Answer (score 1):

The native PHP soap client class can not work with pfx certificates. You have to turn your pfx file into a pem file. For this purpose [install the openssl toolkit](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and run the following command in your shell / command line interface.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ws-hova.pfx -out ws-hova.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

After you 've done creating a pem certificate out of your pfx certificate you can simply use it with the PHP soap client.

```
$certificate = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/ws-hova.pem';
$options = [
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => true,
    'local_cert' => $certificate,
    'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
];

try {
    $client = new SoapClient( $this->api_url, $options );
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This will do the trick. ;)
Have fun.

Comment: There's a typo for anyone else who comes across this answer: SOAP_ATHENTICATION_DIGEST should be SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST .... It won't let me edit since it's less than 6 characters changed